# One layout under the other

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm trying to re-create the animation that the Android L clock app has with it's alarms.
In the animation there is the layout of the general info of the alarm, and when you press it another layout seems to slide from underneath the original layout to show more details, like this:

[image]
[image]

The problem is that I can't seem to be able to show only the top layout when the alarm isn't expanded. I can see the second layout through the first one, and that is not what I want..

here's what I tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:id="@+id/llMainContent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bread"
        android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity: 5"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>
</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/llExpendedContent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llMainContent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

…and then I set the TranslationY of the llExpandedContent to negetive it's own size, and brought the llMainContent above:

```
llExpendedContent.setTranslationY(-(holder.llExpendedContent.getHeight())/mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
llMainContent.bringToFront();
```

but the second layout (the image) is still shown.
Any ideas what can I do?

Comment: Set the visibility to invisible

Comment: but then how would I create the sliding out animation? If I'd have more than one thing in the other layout, how would I make it so only the things that have left the upper layout would be visible? @TimCastelijns